# is there a mechanism similar to operator overload in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

suppose I have a table which has a column days('mon','tue','wed','thu','fri'), how do I implement a days-of-week order (rather than lexicographical order) to them?

eg.

```
'mon'<'tue' //produce true

'fri'>'wed' //true

'fri'<'thu' //false
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I know this is possible in PostgreSQL (with custom datatypes) but I don't think MySQL can do something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the way you want:

```
ORDER BY CASE day
    WHEN 'mon' THEN 1
    WHEN 'tue' THEN 2
    ...
    WHEN 'sun' THEN 7
END
```

**Edit:** you can also create a second table:

```
day_name day_order
======== =========
mon              1
tue              2
...
sun              7
```

... and JOIN and SORT when SELECTing.

Last but not least, store days as numbers :)